# Pass a c# array to a c++ method

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, c++-cli, class-library

I have a CLR class library in c++:

```
namespace ANN_Lib {

    public ref class ANN_FF_BP
    {
    private:
        int neurons;
        int inputs;
        int outputs;

        double **wi;
        double *wl;

    public:
        ANN_FF_BP(int neurons, int inputs, int outputs);

        void Train(double **p, double *t, int pairsCount, int epochs, double goal);
    };
}
```

I am using this class as a reference in a WPF project:

```
ANN_FF_BP neuralNetwork = new ANN_FF_BP(neurons, inputs, outputs);
```

Now I want to call the Train() method (in WPF) from that class and pass in some arguments. I have a problem to pass the first two parameters (pointers) to the method. My current code in C#:

```
ANN_FF_BP neuralNetwork = new ANN_FF_BP(neurons, inputs, outputs);
double[,] P = new double[3, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
double[] T = new double[] { 2, 4, 6 };
neuralNetwork.Train(P, T, 3, 20, 0.01);
```

I get the following error in C#:

[image]

Can anybody explain me how to pass an C# array to a c++ class library method?

Comment: Don't expose native interface from `ref` C++/CLI class. Use .NET arrays in the class interface, which map to C# `double[,]` and `double[]` types: `array<double, 2>` and `array<double>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbydz1t.aspx http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/arrays/multidimension.htm Inside C++/CLI class, if you want to access native data, use `pin_ptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `ANN_FF_BP` is a `ref class` and thus a `CLR` type it's better to pass `.NET` arrays to the `C++/CLI` method and do the *hardwork* there. This way you don't have to declare your `C#` code as [`unsafe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) what would be necessary here if you used pointers in `C#`.

This should work:

`*.h`:

```
void Train(cli::array<double, 2>^ ps, cli::array<double>^ ts, int pairsCount, int epochs, double goal);
```

`*.cpp`:

```
void ClrClass::Train(cli::array<double, 2>^ ps, cli::array<double>^ ts, int pairsCount, int epochs, double goal) {

    // pin pointer to first element in ps
    pin_ptr<double> _ps = &ps[0,0];   
    double* p = _ps;

    // pin pointer to first element in ts
    pin_ptr<double> _ts = &ts[0];
    double* t = _ts;

    // Now with the two arrays being pinned you can call you native method.
    NativeClass::Train((double**)p, t, pairsCount, epochs, goal);
}
```

To protect the arrays from being moved around in memory by the garbage-collector you need to use the [`pin_ptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx):

> A pinning pointer is an interior pointer that prevents the object pointed to from moving on the garbage-collected heap. That is, the value of a pinning pointer is not changed by the common language runtime. This is required when you pass the address of a managed class to an unmanaged function so that the address will not change unexpectedly during resolution of the unmanaged function call.

Comment: @EmirAhmetović you've also deserved a thank you because it is a really high quality question that contains all relevant information so it wasn't _difficult_ I know it's relative ;-) to answer it. Keep it that way ;-]

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder how the solution in unsafe C# looks:

```
unsafe{
    fixed(double* ptr1 = &P[0,0])
    fixed(double* ptr2 = &T[0])
    {
        neuralNetwork.Train(ptr1, ptr2, 3, 20, 0.01);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea if you could extend the example by wrapping it in a method with the `unsafe` keyword so that it's clear that it's necessary.